# ElasticSearch: How to fetch data from fields using ElasticClient from Nest 7.11?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I am using ElasticClient.Search function to get the values of the fields.

**The issue is :**

The code that i make below make the mapping correctly but for searching it returns null values of the fields that was mapped before.

**Main.cs**

```
using Nest;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace DataAccessConsole
{
  class Program
  {
      public static Uri node;
      public static ConnectionSettings settings;
      public static ElasticClient client;
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          {
            node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
              settings = new ConnectionSettings(node).DefaultIndex("getallcommissionspermanentes");
              settings.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p);
              client = new ElasticClient(settings);

              var indexSettings = new IndexSettings();
              indexSettings.NumberOfReplicas = 1;
              indexSettings.NumberOfShards = 1;

              client.Indices.Create("getallcommissionspermanentes", index => index

              .Map<GetAllCommissionsPermanentes>(
                   x => x
                   .AutoMap<GetAllCommissionsPermanentes>()

              ));


               client.Search<GetAllCommissionsPermanentes>(s => s
               .AllIndices()
               );

  }
}
```

**GetAllCommissionsPermanentes.cs**

the table is located in an edmx model of Entityframework and Data came from SQL SERVER Database

```
    public partial class GetAllCommissionsPermanentes
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string NomAr { get; set; }
        public string NomFr { get; set; }
    }
```

**if you need more informations just make a comment below.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Code is correct but '.All Indices ()' searches in all indexes, results that do not match the model are coming. This code will return more accurate results;

```
client.Search<GetAllCommissionsPermanentes>(s => s.Index("getallcommissionspermanentes");
```